# Can't get OpenSSL to run on Windows (same code works fine on Linux)

Tags: windows, openssl

I recently wrote a desktop app for Linux(VirtualBox) that employs openSSL.  I’m just using the libraries for encrypting and decrypting files (no network) and it works great.  Now, I’m trying to create a Windows version and it’s one of the most frustrating things I’ve ever done.

The online community hasn’t been much help (dozens of proposed solutions, all completely different, and none of them work for me).

Specifics:

- I have a 64-bit machine.
- I'm using Qt Creator as my IDE.
- I've downloaded and installed Win64 OpenSSL v1.0.1g from http://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html

The app compiles and runs, but when I get to this line:

```
EVP_EncryptInit(&ctxE, EVP_aes_256_cbc(), constKey, constIv);
```

It crashes with a segmentation fault.

This has been a nightmarish goose chase.  Any help will be greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: What's before the problematic line? The problem may very well be related to something before calling `EVP_EncryptInit`.

Comment: @whowantsakookie - OpenSSL Vahalla is taking shape. It looks like its going to be a hardened OpenSSL by the BSD folks. See [OpenSSL Valhalla Rampage](http://opensslrampage.org/).

Comment: "This has been a nightmarish goose chase...." - so, you're inviting us on that goose chase? How about posting some code so we can do more than guess? You risk having the question closed due to insufficient information.

Comment: You can only post 500 lines here, so the method is too long.  But, remember - the code works fine in Linux.  The only pertinent thing I have before EVP_EncryptInit(&ctxE, EVP_aes_256_cbc(), constKey, constIv);, is the declaration of the cipher object - EVP_CIPHER_CTX ctxE;

Comment: The above code should look like this:        EVP_CIPHER_CTX ctxD;
        EVP_CIPHER_CTX_init(&ctxD);

Answer (score 2):

You did not post any code so I can only guess but if your program is working fine on Linux and exactly the same code segfaults on Windows then you should look at these most common problems:

- Your application must link against the same version of the C runtime libraries against which your openssl was linked and/or you need to include [OpenSSL_Applink](http://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/OPENSSL_Applink.html). There is also a FAQ entry about this topic: [I've compiled a program under Windows and it crashes: why?](https://www.openssl.org/support/faq.html#PROG2)
- 64-bit Windows and 64-bit Linux are two different platforms and as such they require proper handling in your C/C++ code i.e. long takes 8 bytes on 64-bit Linux but only 4 bytes on 64-bit Windows so one bad malloc without the sizeof(long) can cause a serious problem etc.

Comment: There is no "Win32" C runtime.  On Windows, your C runtime isn't provided by the OS, but by your compiler vendor.  (There is `MSVCRT.DLL`, but it's not for your use)

Comment: @BenVoigt Thanks for the comment. I have updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for the info.  In the place where it crashes though, there are no mallocs or long data types.   EVP_CIPHER_CTX ctxD; and then, EVP_CIPHER_CTX_init(&ctxD);  I'm just passing a cipher object to the init function.

Comment: @jariq I looked at the FAQ you suggested.  There's a line in there that's confusing me - "your application must link against the same by which OpenSSL was built".  I don't know what they mean by building OpenSSL.  I downloaded and ran the executable (for Win64 OpenSSL v1.0.1g) from http://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html.  It sets up the directory and sub-directories for OpenSSL called OpenSSL-Win64.  If the libraries and paths are configured in Qt Creator, shouldn't that be enough?  Are there additional steps I have to do?

Comment: @user3548990 Could you please try to use static libraries from OpenSSL-Win64\lib\MinGW\ folder?

Comment: Thanks, everyone for the help.  The powers that be are pulling the plug on this and I'm off on a new project.  Anybody that wants to use it with Windows will have to install VirtualBox and run it on that - it works fine.